# Go to file when following json schema reference ($ref) link in vscode

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, jsonschema, ajv

When clicking on the link of a json schema reference, I would like to go to the corresponding file in VSCode.

For example, let say I've a file named `common.json` with definitions shared across my application.

In an other file I reference one of the definition, like this for example: `email: { $ref: 'https://api.test.com/schemas/common.json#/properties/email' }` (I use ajv [$ref](https://ajv.js.org/guide/combining-schemas.html#a-name-ref-a-combining-schemas-with-ref)).

In VSCode by using option + click (on mac) I can follow the link, but instead of following the link, I would like to go to that file.
Is there anyway to achieve this ? By maybe mapping a url to a file for example, in my case it would be mapping `https://api.test.com/schemas/common.json` to the `common.json` file

Thanks in advance !